# How to do Inception-v3 transfer learning in cntk?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, cntk

I have been studying transfer learning with [cntk tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/release/2.2/Tutorials/CNTK_301_Image_Recognition_with_Deep_Transfer_Learning.ipynb).

After I did this tutorial, I tried to apply another model, and I download InceptionV3_ImageNet_CNTK.model in [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/92738882d1e86c75b75fd08bf5c8872f9e94d697/PretrainedModels/Image.md).

After downloading, when I did

```
node_outputs = C.logging.get_node_outputs(C.load_model('InceptionV3_ImageNet_CNTK.model'))
for l in node_outputs: print("  {0} {1}".format(l.name, l.shape))
```

to strip off the final features layer and attach a new Dense layer for classification, I found that InceptionV3_ImageNet_CNTK.model doesn't have node name.

```
Loading InceptionV3_ImageNet_CNTK.model and printing all layers:
(1000,)
(1,)
aggregateLoss ()
(1,)
aggregateEvalMetric ()
(1000,)
(2048, 1, 1)
(2048, 1, 1)
(2048, 8, 8)
(320, 8, 8)
(320, 8, 8)    
(320, 8, 8)
...
```

Therefore, I can't do

```
feature_node = C.logging.find_by_name(base_model, node_name = model_details['feature_node_name'])
last_node = C.logging.find_by_name(base_model, node_name =  model_details['last_hidden_node_name'])
```

and freeze and attach a new Dense layer.

How to solve this problem?
I've searched all over the internet (Github, StackOverflow, Google...) but I can't seam to find something useful for a novice.

Thanks so much!